# webservice REST método GET com token em navegador externo

Tags: c#, web-service, rest

Estou desenvolvendo um cliente que consome um webservice, todos os métodos POST estão ok.

Tem um método GET que deve retornar uma página em HTML para cadastro de cliente.

nesse método, é necessário definir o header:

> ```
>  content-type:"application/json"    
>  api-token: {token}
> ```

eu consigo chamar o método e abrir a página em um webbrowser, porém com um monte de erros CSS e JS, a formatação da página fica errada e os botões não funcionam.

Gostaria de abrir essa página em um browser externo (chrome, firefox, até mesmo iexplorer) porém, ao chamar a URL, sempre me retorna que o token não foi informado.

É possível mudar algo no C# para abrir corretamente a página no WebBrowser?

É possível abrir o navegador externo, passando além da URL, o token que deve ir no header?

***UPDATE:***

O que já fiz:

1-

```
 string html = LinkedFarma.CadastrarCliente(); //Retorna o HTML do método GET
 webBrowser1.DocumentText = html;
```

*Resultado:* Não carrega CSS e JS (óbvio)

2-

```
string headers = "api-token: "+Configuracao.Token+"\r\n";
headers += "content-type: application/json";
webBrowser1.Navigate(Configuracao.UrlCadastrarCliente, null, null, headers);
```

*Resultado:* Funciona, porém o a página fica com erros, os botões não funcionam o CSS não é carregado completamente.

3-

Já criei uma página em PHP, que receberia o Token como um parâmetro e faria a solicitação redirecionando a página, porém, sem sucesso também. (Me aventurei no PHP pois não tenho prática)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido:

O desenvolvedor da outra empresa, me enviou um exemplo em Delphi e pesquisei como fazer em C#

Ele utiliza um objto OLE que abre o internet explorer.

em C# ficou assim:

```
            SHDocVw.InternetExplorer IE = new SHDocVw.InternetExplorer();
            object Empty = 0;
            object URL = Configuracao.UrlCadastrarCliente;
            IE.Visible = true;

            IE.Navigate2(ref URL, ref Empty, ref Empty, ref Empty, "api-token: "+ Configuracao.Token);
```

obs. Tive que adicionar a referência **Microsoft Internet Controls** de nome: **Interop.SHDocVw**

obrigado a todos pela colaboração.

Answer (score 0):

Pensei que era sua API que estava com problemas para fornecer as paginas estáticas dela, seria um simples ajuste;

Agora que você falou que é um aplicativo desktop, infelizmente nunca trabalhei com Windows Form, sei que tem como abrir a pagina em outro Browser e passar o token, da uma olhada :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293549/setting-authentication-header-for-webbrowser-control-asp-net

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18035579/how-to-open-a-link-in-webbrowser-control-in-external-browser

Comment: a API web é de terceiros, provavelmente feita em java, eu estou fazendo um cliente em windows form com .net 2.0 (somente em ultimo caso para elevar a versão), consumir o método, com token no header está ok dentro da aplicação, porém gostaria de abri-lo em um browser externo devido aos problemas na hora de abrir a página no navegador interno. Obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: Tentou atualizar a versão do .net e verificar se tem uma versão mais recente do Browser interno nas referencias ?

Comment: sim, inclusive fiz uma window em WPF e testei também, mesma coisa =/. O complicado é... fazer a outra empresa alterar o software dela

Comment: Inviável ela fazer isso, pode prejudicar varios clientes; Pelo navegador web externo abre normal a pagina da API? se abre pode tentar migrar seu app para web ou mobile?

Comment: pelo navegador externo, retorna uma mensagem json, dizendo que o token não foi informado. Não é possível a migração porque se trata de uma aplicação para efetuar vendas de convênio, aí tem PAF-ECF no meio e tudo mais

Comment: tentei fazer uma página php, onde eu passo os parâmetros pela url, e o php iria consumir o webservice, consigo abrir a página no navegador, porém não funcional, porque estaria na minha url, e não onde realmente o formulário deve funcionar.

Comment: atualizei a pergunta com mais informações, se puder me ajudar, grato

Answer (score 0):

Existe uma maneira legal de fazer isso no próprio app. Usando o component web, não o nativo da microsoft, mas um de terceiros. Eu utilizo o [awessomium](http://www.awesomium.com/).
Usando a api do mercado livre, segue o exemplo do código que utilizo:

```
    private void formWebControl_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //navega o site da api com os parametros assim que o formulario abrir
        webLogin.Source = new Uri(https://apisite.com);
    }

    private void Awesomium_Windows_Forms_WebControl_TargetURLChanged(object sender, Awesomium.Core.UrlEventArgs e)
    {
        //evento que ocorre quando a url muda no navegador component, daí é só manipular.
        //logo após chama o evento close;
        Close();
    }

    private void formWebControl_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        //limpa o component da memória
        webLogin.Dispose();
    }
```

Creio que isso acima possa te ajudar. Pois ter que ir a um navegador externo, ao meu ver, é muita mão de obra, e esse não é o objetivo de um software.

Espero que seja isso. Qualquer coisa posso colocar o exemplo completo que uso no mercado livre ou até mesmo te ajudar.

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção, então, como é apenas um app que vai integrar dois sistemas, preferimos por nao utilizar componentes externos, normalmente são várias dlls que tenho q referenciar, conseguentemente, várias dlls que terei que distribuir junto da aplicação. Sobre abrir no navegador externo, é apenas uma página, tranquilo. Mais uma vez, obrigado.