# WebBrowser alternativo que rode páginas recentes

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, webview

Eu gostaria de saber se existe algum control para a plataforma .NET que rode páginas atuais sem dar erros.
Eu já procurei no Youtube, no Google, mas nunca acho. O Awesomium.NET não muda. O GeckoFX está desatualizado, e qualquer outro não consigo baixar ou adicionar a referência. Gostaria de uma ajuda.

Comment: Tentei fazer isso também, sem sucesso, mas pelo que vi, a opção seria o chromium.

Comment: Por fim, resolvi meu problema assim: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/201141/69359